# Write IEnumerable extension methods to join a collection of strings

Tags: c#, string, extension-methods, ienumerable

I'm pretty new to C#, and I'm trying to write an extension method to join a collection of objects/strings with custom quote marks. I have 2 ways of implement it, trying to figure out which way is the standard approach.

1st method, define one method for each type I need:

```
public static string JoinToString(this IEnumerable<string> stringEnumerable, string delimiter = ",", char quote = '\'');
{
    return string.Join(delimiter, stringEnumerable.Select(item => quote + item + quote));
}
```

```
public static string JoinToString(this IEnumerable<int> intEnumerable, string delimiter = ",", char quote = '\'')
{
    return string.Join(delimiter, intEnumerable.Select(item => quote + item.ToString() + quote));
}
```

etc...

---

2nd method: define only object parameter so it can work with any type (just like Console.WriteLine(object))

```
public static string JoinToString(this IEnumerable<object> enumerable, string delimiter = ",", char quote = '\'')
{
    return string.Join(delimiter, enumerable.Select(item => quote + item.ToString() + quote));
}
```

which one is the commonly acceptable / standard approach? Thanks!

Comment: You could do either of these but you would probably be better off using Generics which is probably the better solution.

Comment: Why do you want this? Are you trying to generate a CSV file? There are libraries than can do this quickly and efficiently. String operations generate new temporary strings which means generating a CSV line-by-line like that will waste a lot of memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common/ standard approach when working with Linq/ extension methods is to use generics unless you have a reason not to. So

```cs
public static string JoinToString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string delimiter = ",", char quote = '\'')
{
    return string.Join(delimiter, source.Select(item => $"{quote}{item}{quote}"));
}
```

---

For future reference, you can also apply [constraints on the generic type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) if you want to restrict it so only a certain set of types can be passed to the generic method, which is handy when you want to access properties or methods on the object

Comment: I would probably recommend splitting the method into three, one that does the select-part with the quoting, and one that calls string.join, and the third one that composes the previous two. That should make it easier to reuse.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the strongly typed version (1st).
The issue with creating an extension method on `this IEnumerable<object>` is that you will see this extension method on ALL lists as every class inherits of `object`.

In a small codebase this would not be an issue, however I have seen codebases where your IDE and IntelliSense has too many options for irrelevant extension methods.

Keep it simple and small and solve on the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1. Since you implement `public` method you should *validate* input parameters (`enumerable`, `delimiter`)
2. You should check if `item` contains either `delimiter` or `quote`.
3. If `item` contains `delimiter` or / and `quote` you, probably, have to *escape* them
4. You have to check `item` for `null`
5. We usually extend *generic* `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable<object>`

Something like this:

```
public static string JoinToString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                          string delimiter = ",",
                                          char quote = '\'',
                                          char escape = '\'') {

  string Escape(string value) {
    if (escape == '\0') // in case we don't want to escape at all
      return value;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length * 2);

    foreach (var c in value) {
      if (c == quote || c == escape)
        sb.Append(escape);

      sb.Append(c);
    }

    return sb.ToString(); 
  }

  if (source is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
  if (delimiter is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(delimiter));

  return string.Join(delimiter, source
    .Select(item => item?.ToString() ?? "")
    .Select(item => $"{quote}{Escape(item)}{quote}"));
}
```